# Getting an array from collections ordereddict for the maximum key, values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
d
{'A': array([[ 29.503],
       [ 31.829],
       [ 13.078],
       ..., 
       [ 43.227],
       [ 53.028],
       [ 43.928]]), 
'B': array([[  28.738],
       [  68.151],
       [  49.02 ],
       ..., 
       [ 296.73 ],
       [ 107.052],
       [  87.845]]), 
'C': array([[ 11.288],
       [ 31.343],
       [ 71.269],
       ..., 
       [ 92.106],
       [ 34.668],
       [ 41.614]])}
```

if i want to get the maximum of each value of the array A[0], B[0] & C[0], then A[1], B[1] & C[1], ...etc. and return an array [A, B, C..., B] etc.

then use `y = max(d.iterkeys(), key=lambda k: d[k])`

Then it says,

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

So i would like to seek help if i can get an array [A, B, C..., B] etc.?

Thank you

Comment: Please give the code where you define d, not a print out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
np.array(list(d.keys()))[np.hstack(d.values()).argmax(axis=1)]

#array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
#      dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't mix `numpy` with non-`numpy`. What you're looking for is:

```
from numpy import array,concatenate

//DEFINE MATRICES HERE, DONT NEED DICT - I use 'd' for the example, you don\'t need it.

mapping = array(['A','B','C'])
print mapping[concatenate((d['A'],d['B'],d['C']),axis=1).argmax(axis=1)]
```

Explanation:

I took your column arrays, glued them to a matrix where each row is A B C of the form you wanted tested, then `argmax` results in the column index where the maximum is found. Using the 'mapping' I transform the number indices to letters. Try printing without it to understand.